# Check if array value contains browser country code

Tags: php, http-accept-language

I'm trying to show a link to a German version of my landing page if German is one of the browser languages, but the issue I am having is that the array is returning all languages in one value. How can I check to see if the value contains certain letters? Here is the code I am using and the return I see:

```
$langarray = array(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,100));
if(in_array('de', $langarray)){
    $showdelink = '<a style="color: #004f5d;" href="/de/">View the DE homepage</a>';
}
```

I am getting the following returned:

```
Array ( [0] => en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8 )
```

So the issue I am having is the value is not specifically "de", but does contain "de", so the link is not displaying. How can I check that "de" is withing the returned value. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), as

```
if(strpos($langarray[0], "de") !== false) {
    $showdelink = '<a style="color: #004f5d;" href="/de/">View the DE homepage</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly, I will accept this as correct solution in 2 minutes when the question is old enough to accept an answer, I really appreciate it